# Multi AutoComplete TextView when I set text

Tags: android

I have a trouble is `MultilAutoCompleteTextView` don't auto complete when I set text it . this my code

```
listContact = (List<Contact_ID>) readObj(this, "kute");
        ListContactAdapter adapter = new ListContactAdapter(MainAddSms.this, R.layout.layout_getallcontact_item, listContact);
        auto = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAuto);
        auto.setThreshold(1);
        auto.setAdapter(adapter);
        auto.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

        auto.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Contact_IDs apk = new Contact_IDs(null, null);
                apk.setPhoneNumbers(listContact.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
                apk.setNames(listContact.get(position).getName());
                listContactPhone.add(apk);
            }
        });
  auto.setText("09758525244,09758514711");
```

09758525244 = minhml

09738748929= me !

they still work normally when I enter the letters suggest, but when I set the text to it, then it is not working. who can help me?
Thannks for reading

Comment: What do you mean not working? MultilAutoCompleteTextView not shown dropdown or onItemClick not called? If dropdown not shown, try use `setOnFocusChangeListener` and `setOnClickListener`

Comment: it mean , when I settext("09...sth"); on AutotextView , it's not working, but  they still work normally when I enter the letters suggest. I wan't to settext(" ") it still work . Thanks for reading

Comment: I understand that when setText("09..), the dropdown not shown. Have you tried `onTextChanged` yet?

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your issue. Here are the solution for this:

```
multiAutoTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // If wanna filter only the texts are present in TextView, update adapter here
                adapter.clear();
                String text = String.valueOf(s);
                String[] values = text.split(",");
                arrayListMulti = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array)));
                for (String value : values) {
                    for (String original : arrayListMulti) {
                        if (original.contains(value.trim())) {
                           adapter.add(original);
                        }
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                // delay execution to avoid "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid"
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        multiAutoTextView.showDropDown();
                    }
                }, 500);                     
            }
        });

multiAutoTextView.setText("09758525244");
```